# How to pad a n dimensional array

Tags: python, nlp

I have a matrix of word embedding it goes on like -

```
([["word1","word2"...],["word6","word5"....],[...],[....]......])
```

Here the array are sentences and the words are embeddings ,
embeddings have shape (100,)

Not all sentences have the same length I want all the sentences to have the same length I want to pad and trim how can I do it ?

Comment: How exactly do you want to adjust the length of the sentences? Is not clear

Comment: Sentences have different lengths so I took the mean length and I want to pad the sentences with zeros so every sentence has the same length

Comment: And sentences with length longer than the mean length?

Comment: Yes some are longer i was thinking padding a matrices with shape (100,) would work but I don't know how

Comment: An another thing: by length, you mean the number of words or the number of letters?

Comment: Number of words

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my attempt. I started with a simple case where there are three sentences, one with 5 words, one with 3 words, and one with 4 words. The mean is 4, so the last sentence is unchanged, the first is truncated, and the second is padded with 0.

```
sample_sentences = [[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3],[1,2,3,4]]

mean = 0
for element in sample_sentences:
    mean += len(element)

mean = mean/len(sample_sentences)

for element in sample_sentences:
    difference =0

    if (len(element)<mean):
        difference = int(mean)-len(element)
        for i in range (difference):
            element.append(0)


    if(len(element)>mean):
        del element[int(mean):]

print(sample_sentences)
```

Output:
[image]

If you want a zero vector with the length of the difference:

```
sample_sentences = [[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3],[1,2,3,4]]

mean = 0
for element in sample_sentences:
    mean += len(element)

mean = mean/len(sample_sentences)

for element in sample_sentences:
    difference =0

    if (len(element)<mean):
        difference = int(mean)-len(element)
        element.append([0 for x in range(difference)])


    if(len(element)>mean):
        del element[int(mean):]

print(sample_sentences)
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: In my case the number 1,2...5 are Vectors I think I am adding 0s instead big Vectora

Comment: The code should still work if it is an integer making up a vector in rather than a series of strings I believe. Let me change to sample sentence to demonstrate, is this what you are asking?

Comment: It's float actually it's from word2vec

Comment: It should work regardless of the type of the elements composing the matrix, unless there is an issue accessing the matrix with the for..in.., is there an issue when you try applying the method? If there is, would it be possible for me to get an output to play with?

Comment: While padding Instead of adding a vector only zero is added I want to padd a vector of zeros sorry for the confusion this is my first time dealing with big Vectors

Comment: What is the length of the zero vector you want to add? I am actually a bit confused about the structure of the matrix now since I thought "word1" was a string representing a word. You can change element.append(0) to element.append([0,0,...,0]), but this would make the structure of the matrix a bit bizarre since you are padding the zero vector onto a list of strings. Are you saying you want the zero vector appended at the end to be the length of the difference between the mean and the element with length less than mean?

Answer (score 0):

I think you completed stemming.

For the next step, you need to consider how to make data including the similarity between text. Usually, BOW and TD-IDF are used.

please see this article: https://skymind.ai/wiki/bagofwords-tf-idf

Comment: Sorry for not being clear I have some thing like a lists(sentences) within a list that has word vectors

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following simple function: it extend a list with a `filler` element up to a greater length `gl`.

```
def expand(x, gl, filler):
    n = gl - len(x)
    if n > 0:
        x.extend([filler]*n)
```

You can use this simple function. If you want all the sentences to have the same length, you should find the longest sentence and pad the others to match that length:

```
matrix = [["word1", "word2", "myword3"],["word6", "word5"], ["a", "b", "c", "d"]]
maxlength = max(map(len, matrix)) #get the length of the longest sentence

for sentence in matrix:
    expand(sentence, maxlength, "0") #appending 0 to shorter sentences

print(matrix)
```

This prints: `[['word1', 'word2', 'myword3', '0'], ['word6', 'word5', '0', '0'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']]`